# determination to fix the hitch in his giddy-up -- what does that all mean?

Tags: comprehension

Source: [Sams Teach Yourself C++ in 24 Hours (5th Edition)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0672333317)

> This book is dedicated to my dad, who’s currently teaching himself something a lot harder than computer programming: how to walk again after spinal surgery. Through the many months of rehab, you’ve been an inspiration. I’ve never known someone with as much indefatigable determination **to fix the hitch in his giddy-up**.

What exactly are they talking about?

Comment: Google for "hitch in the giddy-up". (0:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[Giddyup!<sup>1</sup>](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/giddyup)** is a command typically directed at a horse or similar animal to encourage it to start moving. In a transferred sense it can be a prompt addressed at other people or even more simplified the process of getting in motion.

A **hitch** is something that doesn't go smoothly, both literally and figuratively. A jerking motion, something stuck or tied down.

So **[a hitch in the giddyup](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=hitch%20in%20the%20giddyup)** indicates a physical / motoric problem in general, often a sign of age or injury.

---

<sup>1</sup> As it's a transcript of an oral command, other spellings occur.